Modify Vacuum fluorescent Display power supply from negative to positive Output voltage
I’ve got a power supply for a vacuum fluorescent display which I want to modify.
It’s giving -31 V anode voltage. The filament is heated by 6 Vac.
I’m not into stuff like that too much but isn’t this a “simple” self oscillating flyback?
I already tried rotating D01, D13, D02 and the the caps of course and get positive voltage, but the circuit consumes twice as much current as the original and ac voltage is 1 V off too. D13, Q02 gets hot to touch. I played with windings orientation but never got a 1:1 change in voltage sign.
I think regulation to Q02 Base with D13 isn’t working this way around but maybe one can help me out?


Tertomium -  Hi, You posted an answer to reply to another answer. However, Stack Exchange has different rules from typical forums (please see the [tour] & [help]) so that post was converted into a comment on the answer you were replying to. || Since you asked the original question, please do not use the text box at the bottom of the screen labeled "Your Answer", unless you have solved your own question, in a different way than any other answer, and are providing that solution to effectively close the question. TY

Yeah, my fault!
Thanks for getting it sorted.

Besides rotating the diodes and capacitors, you ALSO need to "rotate" either the primary turns or the secondary turns.
In other words, you need to switch the "polarity" of the coils either on the input or the output side.
In the picture below, swap 1 and 2 with each other, and 3 and 4 with each other.
Then it should work OK.
The reason why it didn't work is because the flyback and forward converters depend on the polarities of their input and output coils.
You assumed that the output was an AC equal in both directions like in a standard low frequency iron core transformer running on a sine wave, and that's why you didn't understand why it doesn't work as you expected.
A flyback has the input switch (transistor) running current through the primary and building up a magnetic field in the core. During that time the output coil current is induced in the direction which polarizes output diodes in reverse, meaning the diodes block it from reaching the output and there is no output current at that moment.
Once the switch (transistor) turns off, the energy in the built-up magnetic field is now inducing a current in the opposite direction in the output coils and is released through the diodes which are now polarized in their forward direction.


thanks for answering me.
Appreciate your information:-)
I forgot to say I already tried swapping the coils at the input side.
With zener installed with cathode to the output I get 31V output with only 4V input but AC is only 2.8V. With 12V input it draws 700mA and the zdiode and transistor gets very hot. Without z-diode I get 116V vs. GND but 6VAC is working.
So something with the zdiode is wrong. Maybe it needs to be done like this? link
